# Why does acid hydrolysis of glucose-1,6-bisphosphate produce glucose-6-phosphate and not glucose-1-phosphate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, hydrolysis

A [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0009898187900696?via%3Dihub) I found details treating glucose-1,6-bisphosphate with 6M HCl to produce glucose-6-phosphate. I'm curious why glucose-1-phosphate (and then even plain glucose) isn't formed instead?

Comment: You should follow up your reasoning in the question further - think what's the difference between positions 1 and 6?